# How to convert a list containing duplicate values to a dictionary with a list as the value?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Let's say I have two lists generated by another function:

```
test = [[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 5], [1,6], [2, 0], [3, 99], [3, 89], [3, 79]]
test2 = [[1, 4], [4, 1]]
```

I want to convert them to associative arrays for quick lookup like so:

```
test: {0: [1, 2], 1: [5,6], 2: [0], 3: [99, 98, 97]}
test2: {1: [4], 4: [1]}
```

I can do it like this:

```
def list_to_dict(my_list):
    last_val = my_list[0][0]
    temp = []
    my_dict = {}

    for i in my_list:
        if last_val == i[0]:
            temp.append(i[1])
        else:
            #add the values to this key
            my_dict[last_val] = temp
            #reset the list
            temp = []
            temp.append(i[1])

        last_val = i[0]
    my_dict[last_val] = temp
    return my_dict
```

But, that isn't very Pythonic.  Is there a more Pythonic way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> test = [[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 5], [1,6], [2, 0], [3, 99], [3, 89], [3, 79]]
>>> 
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> 
>>> for i, j in test:
...     d[i].append(j)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {0: [1, 2], 1: [5, 6], 2: [0], 3: [99, 89, 79]})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this by dictionary grouping, something like this:

```
    def list_to_dict(my_list):
        d = {}

        for pair in my_list:
            first = pair[0]
            second = pair[1]
            if first not in d:
                d[first] = []
            d[first].append(second)
        return d
```

Or you could use setdefault(), if the key is not available:

```
    def list_to_dict(my_list):
        d = {}
        for pair in my_list:
            d.setdefault(pair[0], []).append(pair[1])
        return d

    # Output 

    {0: [1, 2], 1: [5, 6], 2: [0], 3: [99, 89, 79]}
```

These can easily be manipulated to use defaultdict to if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a perfect use case for `itertools.groupby`:

```
test = [[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 5], [1,6], [2, 0], [3, 99], [3, 89], [3, 79]]

import itertools
d = {k:[t[1] for t in g] for k,g in itertools.groupby(test, key=lambda t: t[0])}

print(d)
```

Note that `groupby` works on iterables, and that it returns a `grouper` object by default. Results are:

```
{0: [1, 2], 1: [5, 6], 2: [0], 3: [99, 89, 79]}
```